# Excel - Date to String with concatenation

Tags: excel

The following line of code works:

`=COUNTIFS('1ST SY: 2021-2022'!$K:$K,A23,'1ST SY: 2021-2022'!$L:$L,"*1/2/2023*") + COUNTIFS('2ND SY: 2021-2022'!$K:$K,A23,'2ND SY: 2021-2022'!$L:$L,"*1/2/2023*") + COUNTIFS('1ST SY: 2022-2023'!$K:$K,A23,'1ST SY: 2022-2023'!$L:$L,"*1/2/2023*")`

The problem is I'm trying to replace the date part:
`"*1/2/2023*"` into something like `(B2 + "*")` but it doesn't seem to work. Take note that `B2` Stands for a date cell.

I have tried replacing it with:

`TEXT(B2, "mm/dd/yyyy") + "*"`

But again, still not working. Can anyone tell me how do I achieve this?

Comment: try replacing the plus with ampersand (&). Also I think you'll need the asterisk at the beginning as well AND your date seems to be in the m/d/yyyy format, so something like: ("\*" & TEXT(B2, "m/d/yyyy") & "\*") should work I think.

Comment: If `B2` is a date cell what's the wildcard hoping to find?  If it's a time part of the date try using `INT(B2)`.

Comment: @andrewb is right, I just figured out, it's not matching because of the m/d/yyyy format. Also Ampersand works great too! Thanks for the reminder!